# How do I specify multiple keys in DataServiceKey attribute for WCF Data Service data context object

Tags: odata, wcf-data-services

I am using Reflection provider for my WCF Data Service and my Data Context object has two key members, say EmpId and DeptId.

If I specify `[DataServiceKey("EmpId", "DeptId")]`, the service doesn't work. When I try to access the collection with the URL `http://localhost:55389/DataService.svc/EmployeeData`, I get the following error:

> The XML page cannot be displayed
>   Cannot view XML input using XSL style
>   sheet. Please correct the error and
>   then click the Refresh button, or try
>   again later. The following tags were
>   not closed: feed. Error processing
>   resource
>   'http://localhost:55389/DataService.svc/EmployeeData'.

With single member in the DataServiceKey, it works fine. I tried with Custom Data Provider and I could achieve this functionality. But if I can do it with the Reflection provider, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the problem is the multiple keys. To confirm please use for example Fiddler or something similar to grab the whole response from the server and share the error in it (as I'm sure there will be one in there).
Guessing from the description I think the problem is that one of your key property values is null. That is not supported and would cause so called in-stream error which would leave the response XML incomplete (which seems to be your case).

Comment: That's is right. Some of the records in my test data had empty DeptId, which was causing the problem. It works fine otherwise. Thanks @Vitek Karas MSFT.

Answer (score 2):

OData can handle multiple keys but all keys must have a valid value. Review [this](http://www.odata.org/documentation/uri-conventions#AddressingEntries) for OData's rule. If you want to retrieve an entry with EmpId=1 and DeptId=someString, you should reconstruct your URI into something like:

`http://localhost:55389/DataService.svc/EmployeeData(EmpId=1,DeptId='someString')`

Be careful in OData queries because they are case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

That is weird, I just tried this:

```
public class Context
{
    public IQueryable<Person> People {
        get {
            return (new List<Person> { 
                   new Person { EmpId = 1, DeptId = 2, Name = "Dude" }     
            }).AsQueryable();
        }
    }
}

[DataServiceKey("EmpId", "DeptId")]
public class Person
{
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    public int DeptId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class WcfDataService1 : DataService<Context>
{
    // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = 
                 DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
    }
}
```

And it works just fine, do you notice any major differences?

-Alex